# What is the proper way to convert an int to wchar_t?

Tags: c++, windows, type-conversion, wchar

Say you have "methods"

```
int Read(...)
{
    unsigned char Byte = 0;
    if(!ReadFile(.., &byte, 1,...))
        return -1;

    return Byte;
}


int ReadBlock(LPWSTR buffer, int cchBuffer ...)
{
    int c = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    do
    {
        if( (c=Read(...)) != -1 )
            buffer[num++] = c; // Here.
    } while( num < ccBuffer );
    return cnt;
}
```

What is the proper way to get that int correctly to WCHAR?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Whats wrong with `(wchar_t)the_int` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used), I realize it was my lack of knowledge about casting that triggered me to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mbstowcs` (multibyte string to wide character string) :

```
int ReadBlock(LPWSTR buffer, int cchBuffer ...)
{
    int c = 0;
    std::vector<char> narrow;
    while((c=Read(...)) != -1 )
       narrow.push_back(c);
    }
    narrow.push_back(0);
    mbstowcs(buffer, &narrow.front(), cchBuffer);
}
```

`mbstowcs` uses the current locale, so that should match the encoding of your input.

Comment: @yanbellavance: Sounds weird. Write a small program that demonstrates the problem, and you can then ask a new question. But you probably will find out the problem yourself when you try to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
convert char <= => wchar
in windows:
MultiByteToWideChar
WideCharToMultiByte

in linux:
mbsrtowcs
wcsrtombs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<tchar.h>

int main()
{
    int integer = 0;
    wchar_t wideCharacter = (wchar_t)integer;

    return 0;

}
```